# Default controller action for each module

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm using module structure for my project. Here is the code that I use to point to default module/controller

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = main 
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = show
```

So far so good. But how to set default controller action for each module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = main 
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = show
```

this part of what you have put into your application.ini sets a *route* to this *module/controller/action* it does not set this as the default module.

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

this line is good for activating modules but it needs to be paired with :

```
resources.modules[] =
```

and make sure each module has an empty Bootstrap.php in the module root that extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`. This is required to make sure loading and routing happens correctly.

Now for setting the default module, put a line like:

```
resources.frontController.defaultmodule = 'default'
```

into your application.ini.

These lines:

```
resources.frontController.defaultcontrollername = 'index'
resources.frontController.defaultaction = 'index'
```

set the default action and controller, but they do it for every module. I don't know of a way to specify a default action for each controller or a default controller for each module.
I usually let index be the default controller and the default action and if I want some other action to happen instead of index I just forward to it:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->+_forward('otherAction');
}
```

Good Luck.